# Is this safe for client side code?

Tags: security, gwt, client

I'm writing a GWT application where users login and interact with their profile. I understand that each form entry needs to be validated on the server, however, I am unsure about potential security issues once the user has logged in.

Let me explain. My application (the relevant parts) works as follows:

1 - user enters email/pass
2 - this info is sent back to the server, a DB is queried, passwords are checked (which are salted and hashed)
3. if the passwords match the profile associated w/ the email, this is considered success

Now I am unsure whether or not it is safe to pass the profile ID back to the client, which would then be used to query the DB for information relevant to the user to be displayed on the profile page.

Is there a possibility for a potential user to manually provide this profile ID and load a profile that way? My concern is that somebody w/ bad intentions could, if they knew the format of the profile ID, load an arbitrary amount of information from my DB without providing credentials.

-Nick

Comment: Perhaps [security.se](security.stackexchange.com) would be a good forum for this question.

Answer (score 3):

What you are dealing with here is a session management issue.  Ideally, you want a way to keep track of logged in users (using random values as the session key), know how long they have been idle, be able to extend sessions as the user is using the site, and expire sessions.

Simply passing the profile ID to the client, and relying on it to send it back for each request is not sufficient - you are correct with your concern.

You want to keep a list of sessions with expiration times in a database.  Every time an action is executed that needs user permissions (which should be pretty much everything), check to see if the session is still valid, if it is, extend it by however long you want.  If it is expired, kill the session completely and log the user out.

You can store your session keys in a cookie (you have to trust the client at some point), but make sure they are non-deterministic and have a very large keyspace so it cannot be brute forced to get a valid session.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're logging a user in, you must be using a backend that supports sessions (PHP, .Net, JAVA, etc), as Stefan H. said. That means that you shouldn't keep any ids on your client side, since a simple id substitution might grant me full access to another user's account (depending on what functionality you expose on your client, of course).

Any server request to get sensitive info (or for any admin actions) for the logged in user should look something like getMyCreditCard(), setMyCreditCard(), etc (note that no unique ids are passed in).

Comment: Those backend systems are simply doing what I described.  The client always has to have some sort of token that it passes to the server with each request.  Those frameworks simply obfuscate what is going on from the developer.  And the simple id substitution is always a chance.  The trick is to make it impractically difficult to attempt every session id in the keyspace to attempt to hijack a user's session.

Comment: Stefan, I'm basically complementing your comment -- we're saying the same thing (I didn't feel the need to repeat what you've already said) :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility for a potential user to manually provide this profile ID and load a profile that way? My concern is that somebody w/ bad intentions could, if they knew the format of the profile ID, load an arbitrary amount of information from my DB without providing credentials.

Stefan H is correct that you can solve this via session management if your session keys are [unguessable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) and [unfixable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).

Another way to solve it is to use crypto-primitives to prevent tampering with the ID.

For example, you can store a private key on your server and use it to [sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) the profile ID.  On subsequent requests, your server can trust the profile ID if it passes the signature check.

Comment: Yes, very good point.  Encrypting the profileID before sending it to the client would be acceptable and would prevent direct manipulation of the profileID to hijack a session.  Including a timestamp in the encrypted payload would allow for the session management aspects to be implemented.

Comment: @StefanH, yep, and if each profile has its own key, then session revocation is just a matter of rotating the key.

Answer (score 0):

Rule 1 - `Avoid cooking up your own security solution and use existing tested approaches`.

Rule 2 - If your server side is java then you should be thinking along the lines of jsessionid. Spring Security will give you a good starting point to manage session ids with additional security features. There will be similar existing frameworks across php too (i did not see server side language tags in the question).

Rule 3 - With GWT you come across javascript based security issues with Google Team documents and suggests XSRF and XSS security prevention steps. Reference - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/security_for_gwt_applications